# How to execute a SQL Agent Job on a button click in a Web Part page of a SharePoint 2013 site?

Tags: web-part, javascript, client-object-model, content-editor-web-part, sql-server-2012

I have a SharePoint 2013 on-premises site. The requirement is to add a button to one of the Webpart pages and on click of that button, a sequence of 3 consecutive SQL Server Agent jobs will be executed. Also in the same Web Part page there should be a non-editable text-field displaying the current status of the JOB in process, something like:

1. Job1 started at 10:23:34 PM.
2. Job1 completed at 10:25:00 PM.
3. Job2 started at 10:25:10 PM.
4. Job2 failed at 10:26:00 PM. An e-mail has been sent to the Admin with Log details.

Any help/suggestions on how to achieve this?

P.S: Only Client-side code is expected as we don't have highest level of access to the site.